# Opencl Error for mac OS X Mavericks ( ld: library not found for -lshrutil_x86_64 )

Tags: macos, opencl, osx-mavericks

I have upgraded my OS X to mavericks. Earlier I was able to run the OpenCL samples available on Nvidia Cuda site. But recently I tried to run sample code of OpenCL but it is showing the error - ld: library not found for -lshrutil_x86_64

I downloaded a example from this site..
https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl

Please tell me if any upgrade for OpenCL is required for OS X Mavericks. Or do I need to set any lib path explicitly ???